# What sort of SPD pedals should I use for cyclocross?

Tags: pedals, cyclocross

So I do cyclocross and have recently got some SPD cleats, the problem is my pedals are eggbeaters which isn't great.

I was thinking in investing in some half and half pedals (like [enter these](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/shimano-a530-spd-single-sided-touring-pedals?sku=5360266236&source=igodigital)) or some double sided with a pedal around it (like [these](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/shimano-m424-spd-pedals/)). What do you guys think would be best for cyclocross?

Comment: May CX riders use eggbeaters because of the 4-sided entry. But since you want to switch to SPD, use normal double-sided SPD pedals http://www.wiggle.co.uk/shimano-pd-m520-pedals/, without a cage. Cages tend to become clogged on muddy terrain. And they may have sharp edges that can cause injury.

Comment: @Carel a cage lets me be able to step on the peddle and and peddle with needing to clip in which can take a second though

Comment: @Carel but flats would be acceptable wouldn't they? I've got the M424s linked above on one bike and I'm about to buy another pair for another bike (commuting etc.) and I'd rather be hit by the cage on that than most flat pedals. Mud and clogging is another matter. Having ridden on single sided SPDs I reckon they're the worst of both worlds.

Comment: Why not keep the eggbeaters and get correct cleats? If clipping in is a problem, keep practicing.

Comment: Crank Brothers makes all sorts of pedals around their egg beater design, I use the Candy's which is just the Egg Beater with a little bit of platform around the egg beater, making it dual sided. As others have said, the biggest benefit for me is clearing the mud. I can still ride with flat shoes for getting around town. Replacement egg beater cleats should be available at most local bike shops.

Comment: Some love double sided pedals, I dislike them even for casual riding. For cyclocross you need to clip without looking and know it will be there, double sided does no give you this.

Comment: @Ben Poulter: You can start pedalling right away on a double-sided pedal without the need to clip in. Whereas with a single-sided SPD you'll have to flip the pedal before being able to do so. It will cost time and need attention, a potential source of distraction and crash in a race.